# You do not have permissions necessary to view the contents

Tags: permissions, mount, nautilus

Every time I plug in a USB drive on Ubuntu 16, it mounts it, but when I try to view contents in Nautilus, I get the error:

```
You do not have permissions necessary to view the contents of "<USB Mount Folder>"
```

Other users have reported a temporary fix by doing:

```
sudo chown <myuser>: <path to mount folder>
```

but I have to do this everytime I plug in the drive. That is clearly insane as I'm the user mounting it, so it should automatically be accessible to me.

How do I fix this permanently? This didn't happen in Ubuntu 14, which correctly mounted drives with the correct permissions.

Comment: What file system is on the usb ?

Comment: Does this happen only on that machine?

Comment: *That is clearly insane as I'm the user mounting it, so it should automatically be accessible to me*  No, not really. If it is a Linux/Unix file system and you are not the owner than that behavior is expected, hence the need to `chown`.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's expected file system behavior, "_How do I fix this permanently?_" is a valid question.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Ext4.

Comment: @MichaelBay, What's the purpose of not automatically chowning? I physically possess the drive, so it's not as though I'm trying to "hack" someone else's machine. Requiring the user to chown their own drive, regardless of the user permissions, is a unnecessary exercise and therefore a design flaw. The fact that this didn't happen for me under Ubuntu 14 would suggest that it's a regression or bug.

Comment: @Cerin Nobody is saying or even suggesting wrong doing but just pointing out the whole concept of ownership/permissions in a multiuser oriented OS. It has been part of the any GNU/Linux core features from the beginning and were inherited from the good ol'Unix. Coming from Windows you're understandably used to a dumbed down and unavoidably less safe user experience.

Comment: @MichaelBay, Coming from Windows? I haven't used Windows in 15 years. I've never encountered this error until Ubuntu 16.